# Scanned image after converting it to PDF is blurry

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext, java.util.scanner

I'm scanning a document to an image stored in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Then from the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, I create a PDF using iText, but the image in that PDF is blurred and not visible at all. If we scan small document, it's OK, but when we scan a sheet of size , it gets saved as a blurred image inside the PDF.

We tried various way to improve the quality but nothing improved the quality. 
I tried converting the image to a print stream, but that made it even more blurred than before.

```
Component[] comps = MainPanel.this.getComponents();
List<ImagePanel> scannedImages = new ArrayList<ImagePanel>();
for (Component c : comps) {
    if (c instanceof ImagePanel) {
        scannedImages.add((ImagePanel) c);
    }
}
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
try {
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
    document.open();
    for (ImagePanel p : scannedImages) {
        com.lowagie.text.Image iTextImage = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(p.getImage().getScaledInstance(documentWidth, documentHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), null);
        document.add(iTextImage);
        document.newPage();
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
} 
    document.close();
 DocumentUploadInfo.setDocumentStream(output.toByteArray());
 DocumentUploadInfo.setDocumentMIMEType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: Also tried to increase the resolution from 300 to 600 it has small change but not clear enough

Comment: Can you please post the first few bytes of your file? Just to make sure you aren't trying to generate pdfs from random bytes. PS: you can edit your original post to include more information, rather than doing it in comments.

Comment: Could you also post your code?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    try {
     PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
                    document.open();
                    for (ImagePanel p : scannedImages) {
                        com.lowagie.text.Image iTextImage = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(p.getImage().getScaledInstance(documentWidth, documentHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), null);
                        document.add(iTextImage);
                        document.newPage();
                    }

Comment: When I see my name in other people's code, I know that they are using a version that [should no longer be used](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). The version you are using dates from July 2009 or earlier. That's nothing to be proud about. Please throw away your code, and start anew with a more recent iText version. This being said: iText doesn't change a single pixel in your image, but you change the resolution when you scale the image using the `ImagePanel` class. Why do you even scale the images? Why don't you adapt the page size to the size of the image?

Comment: Isn't the image format of images saved in pdf usually jpeg? That has all the potential to make it blurry...